# Scraping a text inside a button

Tags: python, scrapy

may I kindly request your help? 
I am trying to scrape the following site: 
http://www.milsims.com.au/

1) In the first page I am grabbing game title and price however I cannot extract the text from the button "add to cart". (I have called it item "stock" in the code below).

2) the URL item is not extracting full URL just a "node"

3) for some reason, the price item in the code is bugging as well. ("list index out of range")

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong?

Thanks !

```
import scrapy

class MilSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'mil'
allowed_domains = ['milsims.com.au']
start_urls = ['http://www.milsims.com.au/catalog/1746'

]

def parse(self, response):
    for product in response.css(".view-advanced-catalog tr > td"):
        item = {}
        item['name'] = product.css(".views-field-title a ::text").extract_first()
        item['old_price'] = product.css(".views-field-phpcode span span::text").extract()[0]
        item['new_price'] = product.css(".views-field-phpcode span span::text").extract()[1]
        item['stock'] = product.css(".views-field-buyitnowbutton span span::text").extract()
        item['url'] = product.css(".views-field-title a ::attr(href)").extract()            
        yield item

    next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Problem with price occurs at page 2 when there is no discount price, just regular price :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your css selector is matching empty `span` elements. What you need instead is match the button itself, which is an `input` element with a type of `submit`, and extract its `value`.
2. The url in the source is relative, you can use [response.urljoin()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) to get an absolute url.
3. Either check the length of the returned list, or use a different selector for the two prices.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments ! I am not very familiar with coding, could you please suggest edits directly in my code?

Comment: Regarding item 3, see this link. The problem is at the item "Coney Island"  http://www.milsims.com.au/catalog/1746?page=1   ... it is working good until it reaches that item

Comment: Hi if you can help modifying my code I really appreciate! Thanks